# What's the maximum rf fm signal that i can generate using raspberry pi?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, ffmpeg, pifm

I am planning to create a raspberry pi based monitoring system where my raspberry pi acts as a transmitter. I learned that we can use pi to generate FM signals from [RPiTX project](https://hackaday.com/2015/11/04/rpitx-turns-rasberry-pi-into-versatile-radio-transmitter/).

I am planning to generate a BPSK modulated signal using my pi and would like the signal to be about 470-570MHz around the tv bands. Is this possible?

I have seen netizens already producing up to couple of MHz in 400 ish range using 3rd harmonic component as their actual signal however its nowhere near my expected frequency :(

Comment: google `software defined radio`

Comment: I actually have sdr as a receiver in my project. Since transceiver sdr are very costly I want raspberry pi to be my transmitter.

Comment: " am planning to generate a BPSK modulated signal using my pi and would like the signal to be about 470-570MHz **around the tv bands**. " - why?

Comment: Its part of a larger project actually. Why TV bands because those where the bands that where free in my area where i am implementing this project. i don't want to use ISM because I just want to try something new and this is on a very small scale so there is also no problem of interference with some other signals out there.